# Query a specific index value of a multivalue field in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have the following field in the solr

```
productName = "Iphone"
Store = ["store1", "store2", "store3"]
Price = [100,200,150]
```

Iphone has different prices in different stores, so I want to make a query for one store at a time.

```
store1 price = 100, store2 price = 200, store3 price = 150.
```

For Example, Filter all the store1 products where prices are in the range of 150 to 200

Comment: Index each value as a separate field - define a dynamic integer field with a common prefix, for example `price_store_xyz`, and you can then query `price_store_xyz:[150 TO 200]`. Another option is to have separate documents for each store + price combination, and then query that way.